# Concatenate/merge tables in R

Tags: r, merge, concatenation

I have some tables `Table1`,`Table2`,`Table3`,`Table4`. They have the same number of `columns` and `rows` and what I want is to `merge` them into one big `Table`.

I have tried making a list of the tables and then converting it to a `matrix` but the output doesn't seem what I want.

```
l <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)
l <- lapply(l, as.data.frame)
m <- matrix(unlist(l), nrow = length(l))
```

I have also tried to just `merge` the four tables using `merge(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)` but I am not sure about providing the proper arguments and therefore I get an error.

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) :
>     'by' must specify one or more columns as numbers, names or logical
>   Calls: merge -> merge.data.frame -> fix.by

I have also tried to write the tables to an external `.txt` file and then read from that file a new table.

```
#write.table(Table1, file = "file.txt", append = TRUE)
#write.table(Table2, file = "file.txt", append = TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
#write.table(Table3, file = "file.txt", append = TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
#write.table(Table4, file = "file.txt", append = TRUE, col.names=FALSE)
```

However this solution is inadequate for various reasons and I had to drop it.

By the way I would prefer the first solution to somehow work.

***Edit:*** I forgot to mention that all four tables have identical indexes `1,2,3,..,` and same columns names, etc. I am pointing this out because for example `cbind` doesn't fit well.

I am pretty sure this is a trivial task but I am stuck. Any help?

Comment: How do you want your final output? If all tables have same number of columns, do you want to just append the data horizontally( by rows) or vertically?

Comment: @RHelp Append them vertically so i can reindex the table

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is still a problem of different headings. This should do the trick:

```
names(table2) <- names(table1)
names(table3) <- names(table1)
names(table4) <- names(table1)
```

Do this for every table and then

```
rbind(table1,table2,...)
```

If you want to know if the headings are the same, you could compare them

```
names(table1) == names(table2)
```

etc.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `rbind`

try

```
do.call(rbind, list(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4))
```

Comment: i am actually trying `cbind` but i doesn't quite do what i want. I will update the question

Comment: `Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
  names do not match previous names
Calls: do.call -> <Anonymous> -> rbind -> match.names
Execution halted` this is what i get from `rbind`

Comment: Check if your column names match in all tables. colnames(table1),colnames(table2),etc. R is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

rbind should work if all your columns are the same in all tables. Follow Chinmay's answer. cbind is for concatenating data on columns. Else use sqldf.

```
library(sqldf)
m <- sqldf("select * from table1 union all select * from table2 union all 
             select * from table3 union all select * from table4")
```

Use union all if you want all your observations. Use union if you want to remove the duplicates.
But this might be slower than rbind if your data sets are large.

Comment: concatenating data in columns is what i want actually. that is why i answered `append vertically` in your question. alright i look that up too

Comment: Append vertically means adding more rows of observations to your existing data right?

Comment: yeap. Oh now i am starting to get it.. however `rbind` generates an error which probably means that i have others problems..

Comment: its in the comment section of the answer @ChinmayPatil gave me

Answer (score 0):

you can use Reduce with merge :

```
l <- list(Table1, Table2, Table3, Table4)
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), l)
```

hth

Comment: i might be doing something wrong but `reduce` returned a list containing name columns for each table, which is weird

Comment: I modified my answer which works with the following example: table1 <- data.frame(x=letters[1:2], y=rpois(2,4)), table2 <- data.frame(x=letters[3:4], y=rpois(2,4)), table3 <- data.frame(x=letters[5:6], y=rpois(2,4)), l <- list(table1, table2, table3), Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all=T), l)